# How to add another postgres username when there are multiple postgresql installations on linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have 2 installations of postgresql servers 9.1 and 9.4 running on linux ports 5432 and 5433 respectively. When I switch user using command su postgres, it switches user of older version i.e of 9.1.  Is there some command to su postgres of 9.4 using '-p'  port option ? How do I create a username 'postgres' for the new postgresql install i.e for version 9.4

Comment: `su postgres` merely switches to the Linux user named `postgres`. It doesn't execute any PostgreSQL-related commands (e.g. `psql`).

Comment: `su postgres` & then specify the port to connect to your different servers

Comment: @HaleemurAli, thank you. works great!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

su postgres & then specify the port to connect to your different servers

@HaleemurAli, thank you. works great

Answer (score 1):

There is probably only one user `postgres`.

What you observe is probably that environment variables like `PATH` and `PGDATA` are set up for PostgreSQL 9.1.

You can either use the absolute paths to refer to the PostgreSQL executables (e.g. `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pgctl`) and specify the data directory explicitly with the `-D` option, or you can edit `.bash_profile` and add the environment variables there to be automatically set when you log in.